# Prevent windows computers from remembering last account with group policy

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I have computers joined to an active directory domain. My users have roaming profiles because they will be using different computers in the office. Currently the computers will default the username to the last person who logged in. Where In group policy is the setting to make it so that users have to enter their username every time they log in?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Group Policy object to prevent this:

The path to it is

> Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local
>   Policies > Security Options > Interactive logon: Do not display the
>   last logged on user name`